# Using ffmpeg library with Qt framework results in error

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, ffmpeg, qt4

When I include:

```
extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
}
```

I am getting the error:

> undefined reference to QVideoSurfaceFormat::QVideoSurfaceFormat(QSize
>   const&, QVideoFrame::AVPixelFormat, QAbstractVideoBuffer::HandleType)

without the include - build success.

My guess that include brings some defines that breaks QVideoSurfaceFormat defenition.
Have someone faced with the similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS // to fix #include <stdint.h> issue
extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}
```

After reading through stdint.h and related topic in the web, found solution, that works for me:

```
#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
```